# Is this sentence correct "The reason is actually because of another issue #176"?

Tags: word-choice

I found an issue of a software, and finally I found the root cause if another issue, so I tell others:

> The reason is actually because of another issue #176

But I'm not sure if that's a valid or native English expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could say it that way. For the software implementation profession, better wording would be ...

> The cause is actually due to another issue (#176).

Comment: Or "...due to another issue, #176."

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: English is not my first language.

It does not look accurate to me. Looks like the author wants to say that the issue in question (say 999) is due to issue 176.

> This issue occurs because of issue #176.